# iOS CocoaTouch - LocalAuthentication Framework : What Significance and Use of _ErrorType defined Code Enum In LAError

Tags: swift, localauthentication

I was trying to understand the usage and significance of the typealias marked for code enum declared in the LAError class for the LocalAuthentication framework provided for iOS SDK. I have marked the same in the screenshot attached.

What is the significance and use of the _ErrorType declared inside the LAErro.Code enum?

[image: Reference Image]

Any lead on this that which would help me understand would be greatly appreciated.

Corresponding Code Snippet for the image :

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public struct LAError {

    public init(_nsError: NSError)

    public static var errorDomain: String { get }


    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public enum Code : Int {

        public typealias _ErrorType = LAError
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture. Pictures can't be searched, referenced, or copied, and they are harder to post.

Answer (score 0):

`typealias` is used to refer anything with another name. e.g.

```
var ErrorBlock=(ErrorType?) -> Void
typealias ErrorCallback = ErrorBlock
```

so `ErrorCallback` and `ErrorBlock` represent same object.

Here is [link](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2016/06/24/typealias-for-great-good/), which shows many benefits of typealias. On the summary, here is the list of other examples from the link:

```
typealias Name = String
typealias Employees = Array<Employee>
typealias GridPoint = (Int, Int)
typealias CompletionHandler = (ErrorType?) -> Void
```

Comment: My question is with regards to the significance of the _ErrorType declared in the LAError.Code enum not the usage and benefits of typealias.